# How can I reset the cron task with elysia cron?

Tags: cron, drupal-7

I can't reset the cron task.
I did force run than ran the cron and nothing. mymodule_queue_function - doesn't execute and the $count always increases.
I was trying reset count in maintenance settings (reset statistics) but it doesn't work.
How can I fix it?

```
mymodule_cronapi($op, $job = NULL) {
  $items['functions_cron_month_prepare'] = array( 
    'description' => 'users pay for services', 
    'rule' => '4 0 24 * *',
    'arguments' => array(5),
    'callback' => 'mymodule_select_month_prepare', 
  );
  return $items; 
}

// /** * Implementation of hook_cron_queue_info() */ 
function tariffing_cron_queue_info() {
  $queues['mymodule_queue_main'] = array(
    'worker callback' => 'mymodule_queue_function',
    'time' => 3600,
    );
  return $queues;
}

function mymodule_select_month_prepare() {
 if($users) {
      foreach ($users as $usr) {
        $usr_s[$usr['uid']][] = $usr['service_name'];
      }

      $n = round(count($usr_s)/4);
      $items = count($usr_s) > 4 ? array_chunk($usr_s, $n, true) : array(0 => $usr_s);

      $queue = DrupalQueue::get('mymodule_queue_main');
      foreach ($items as $item) {
        $count = $queue->numberOfItems();
        $queue->createItem($item);
      }
    }
}

function mymodule_queue_function($data) {
  watchdog('$data_users', print_r($data,true));
}
```

Comment: The problem is relevant.
Is somebody have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved by replacing the name of the function. But appeared another problem:
The time of my cron task is (4 0 1 * *) but now 25th day, and the job task was executed. Why?? What did I wrong?
Could did it happen case I deleted all cron execution statistics?